# How to lay out two unsteady alternating box sizes (1/3 and 2/3 in width) properly?

Tags: css

Initially I wanted to accomplish the following [layout](http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/havuH). It is just a mockup. The crux - the final layout should be in Wordpress and instead of the colored backgrounds there should be images pulled from the media library.

Basically it is a list of articles (over time they could increase or decrease in number). Therefor I was looking for an automated CSS solution covering the cases. But so far I am unable to think of a nth-child code to catch all 1/3 cases at once and another for the 2/3. Both cases are unsteady. So I came up with the [idea](http://codepen.io/rpkoller/details/moulG) having two nth-child cases for each box type. Is that a valid solution or is there room to improve and make things more elegant?

Best regards Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
article:nth-child(4n+1) instead of .onethirdLeft
article:nth-child(4n+2) instead of .twothirdRight
article:nth-child(4n+3) instead of .twothirdLeft
article:nth-child(4n) instead of .onethirdRight
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tqKpz